# Phonegap splashscreen orientation

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

When setting the splashscreen for a phonegap application, the picture gets stretched across the whole screen, even when i make a big picture with the logo in the center. Ideally I want the picture just sit in the center with a black or white background. How can I configure the behaviour of the splashscreen?

Answer (score 12):

There is a better solution available: Simply place the following splash.xml in res/drawable (modify the *android:src* attribute) and change the reference to R.drawable.splash, in the setIntegerProperty() call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/splashImage"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

Please see my [Blog](http://www.acoveo.com/acoveo/?q=en/using-a-centered-splash-screen-with-phonegap) for a more detailed description of the set-up.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Put splash.bmp and splash.xml into res/drawable-xhdpi and super.setIntegerProperty( "splashscreen", R.drawable.splash ); into my_app.java

Comment: Make sure you don't name the bitmap splash, but something else (splashImage.bmp). Also put a copy of the file into res/drawable. You might also want to convert the file to .png to save some space.

Comment: don't use capitals in a filename, wont work, use splashimage.bmp

Comment: I was having trouble with this as well. My android app was originally using PNG's saved in `/drawable-port-xhdpi/splash.png`, `/drawable-port-mdpi/splash.png`, `/drawable-port-ldpi/splash.png` and `/drawable-port-hdpi/splash.png`. I tried referencing my new `splash.xml` by placing it in drawable directory but that didn't work. So, I had to create a `splash.xml` file to replace each of the `splash.png` files and then rename `splash.png` to `splashimage.png` (note the comment about lowercase) in each directory. Hope this helps people.

Answer (score 3):

I just set the splash screen based on the current orientation on startup.  Not perfect, but works.  You could go further and ad on orientation change the same effect, but the chances of someone changing orientation during splash screen startup is slim.

```
int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (ot == 2) {
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashlandscape);
            Log.d("Orientation", "Landscape");
        }
        else {
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashportrait);
            Log.d("Orientation", "Portrait");
        }
```

Comment: After many searches this is the only real solution for cordova 2.o

Comment: I'm surprised the same solution works there, this code was from phonegap 1.0.  I haven't messed with the new version yet so I don't know if there is a better solution now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution but it has flaws

put your splash.png in the various drawable folders

```
res/drawable/splash.png (480wx800h portrait version)
res/drawable-land/splash.png (800wx480h landscape version)
```

known issue with this method is if the orientation changes after load it doesn't update the background... (this is true for phonegap 1.10)

Comment: Tried it before, but it had the described problem, when changing orientation while loading.